# Compile FFmpeg with a new encoder

Tags: ffmpeg

I have be sent a encoder and I need to compile with FFMPEG, I am new to this so I'm not sure how to add/compile it with ffmpeg. The encoder is JSV, my server is ubuntu 14.04.

I have started to read this https://ffmpeg.org/developer.html#New-codecs-or-formats-checklist but am unsure about what to do.

Comment: What is JSV? Have you looked at the git log for examples? You can look at the git web interface and view the diff of the initial commit. [libx265](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=bb6b1731eba2fac424ff8ad3003fe58b308debd1) and [nvenc](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=2a428db5e2c1d10ff5a7d5e8352eef8d195d440c) for example (there are much simpler ones too).

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the issue, it was mainly to do with the configuration of my ffmpeg, I had configured my ffmpeg incorrectly at the bginning, thanks for the reply.

Comment: How did you solve the issue exactly? Others wanting to do something similar could benefit from a more helpful answer.